# How to plot a graph for a function having a singularity point

Tags: python, numerical-methods, differential-equations

I am trying to plot a solution curve (u~v) for the following first-order differential equation:

(u/v)(dv/du) = (1-u)/(u+v-3)

which has boundary condition as:
v=0 at u=3
and
dv/du= -5/3 at (3,0)

I am supposed to get a curve that spirals around the singular point (1,2).
But, I could not obtain the desired plot. Can anyone write the code in python for the above equation?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Im not that good or the question is not explained enought but i put it in Wolframalpha and it treturn this[image]